# Variable not being read as a system property

Tags: scala, groovy, logback

I am trying to read variables in my logback configuration from system properties but without success. I define a very simple logback.groovy as below:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender

import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.DEBUG

appender("FILE", FileAppender) {
  file = "${USER_HOME}/myApp.log"
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%msg%n" 
  }
}
root(DEBUG, ["FILE"])
```

Then a simple Test.scala:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object Test {

        val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

                log.debug("Where does the logging go?")

        }
}
```

And run

> sbt -DUSER_HOME="/tmp"

But logback does not pick up the system property. Below is the output when I run the program:

> 22:03:30,768 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] -
>   Found resource [logback.groovy] at
>   [file:/home/des/workspace/play/target/scala-2.10/classes/logback.groovy]
>   22:03:31,449 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@5c3286d0 - About
>   to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender]
>   22:03:31,450 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@5c3286d0 - Naming
>   appender as [FILE] 22:03:31,515 |-ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.AppenderDelegate@7930f0f9 - Appender
>   [FILE] of type [ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender] has no appplicable
>   [USER_HOME] property  22:03:31,556 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to
>   [null/myApp.log] 22:03:31,562 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@5c3286d0 - Setting
>   level of logger [ROOT] to DEBUG 22:03:31,569 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@5c3286d0 -
>   Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]

Note that when I define the USER_HOME in my logback file it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because I am using groovy. Thinking it was a logback bug I reported it such and was resolved thus: http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1041

Answer (score -1):

You need to do the following

```
sbt '; set javaOptions += "-DUSER_HOME="/tmp" ; runMain Test'
```

or

change your `build.sbt` to include

```
fork := true

envVars := Map("USER_HOME" -> "/tmp")
```

If you want to run from a production env without using `sbt` you can pass it directly (using -DUSER_HOME="/tmp") to the run script generated when you create a Play distribution (using the `dist`) command.

Comment: Afraid that does not solve the issue. The system property is being set correctly. Which can be proved by adding a println("Prop: " + System.getProperty("USER_HOME")) to the main() method